# Adding up fix value into list of bigdecimal

Tags: java, java-8, bigdecimal

I want to adding up fix value into list of big decimals.
lets say i have below list of big decimal with values

```
[10, 20, 30, 40]
```

Now want to add fix value lets say `10` into each item into list so resulting list would be

```
[20, 30, 40, 50]
```

**Current approach** :

```
public static void main(String... args) {
        List<BigDecimal> bigDecimals = new ArrayList<>();

        bigDecimals.add(new BigDecimal(10));
        bigDecimals.add(new BigDecimal(20));
        bigDecimals.add(new BigDecimal(30));
        bigDecimals.add(new BigDecimal(40));
        System.out.println(bigDecimals);

        for(int i=0;i<bigDecimals.size();i++)
        {
            bigDecimals.set(i, bigDecimals.get(i).add(new BigDecimal("10")));
        }

        System.out.println(bigDecimals);
    }
```

**Is there any better way or alternative way using java 8?**

Comment: What is an 'fix value'? Do you mean *fixed*?

Comment: @EJP yup. Let's say initial value of the list is [10, 20, 30, 40] 
by adding fixed value "10" . resulting list would be [20, 30, 40, 50]
Explanation is already provided into the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In java 8 it's as simple as

```
bigDecimals.replaceAll(BigDecimal.TEN::add);
```

See the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-)  for `List#replaceAll`

Comment: this seems to be working but when we do   bigDecimals.replaceAll(BigDecimal.TEN::substract);  it is resulting some thing else than it should be.

Comment: To subtract TEN, you will need to either write out the lambda expression `d -> d.subtract(TEN)` or use `TEN.negate()::add`.  That's because addition is commutative while subtraction isn't.

Answer (score 1):

That's a simple map operation...

```
bigDecimals.stream().map(bd -> bd.add(BigDecimal.TEN)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response , but original list is not getting updated using above mentioned solution.

Comment: @SnehalPatel my bad... you got your answer by now anyhow :)